# Angular: Injecting classes without @Injectable decorator

Tags: angular

I have some classes that come from a library, e..g.:

```
class Foo {
   // ...
}
class Bar {
   constructor(private foo: Foo) { }
   // ...
}
```

These classes don't have the `@Injectable` decorator because the library isn't Angular-specific. However, I want to use them in my app as services.

My solution so far has been to create derived classes, e.g.:

```
@Injectable()
class InjectableFoo extend Foo {
  constructor() { super(); }
}
@Injectable()
class InjectableBar extends Bar {
  constructor(foo: InjectableFoo) {
    super(foo);
  }
}
```

I'm not very thrilled with this solution, because it requires extra boiler-plate code that adds no real value, and the person consuming these services in a component has to know to use the "Injectable" versions instead of the (simpler) base classes. In a perfect world I'd like to be able to tell Angular that `Foo` and `Bar` should be injectable.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could extend your classes in your Angular app and make it `Injectable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide them in the `NgModule` using a factory provider, and a value provider.

https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider

https://angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider

```js
class Foo {
   // ...
}
class Bar {
   constructor(private foo: Foo) { }
   // ...
}

@NgModule({
   providers: [
      {provide: Foo, useValue: new Foo()},
      {provide: Bar, useFactory: (foo) => new Bar(foo), deps: [Foo]}
   ]
});
```

In the above example you can use `useValue: new Foo()`, but the key here is that the `deps: [Foo]` allows you to inject `foo` into the factory function for `Bar` since it is a dependency.

Later in the components you can just do the following.

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) { }
}
```

Comment: `useFactory` is exactly what I was looking for -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide it in the `@NgModule()` class decorators in your `app.module`:

```
@NgModule({
 ...Others Imports/Declare
 providers: [ Foo, Bar ]
})
```

This will allow Angular Dependecy Injector to see those class (also make them a singleton when they injected to others component)

Then inject it like others service

```
export class YourComponent{
  constructor(private fooInstace: Foo){}
  ...
}
```